# How to Run a script on USB removal?

Tags: linux, udev, usb-drive

I want to execute the script on removal of usb drive. In that script I want to restart the server.
Is there any way to do the same ? 
I know I have to modify the rules in /etc/udev/rules.d/.

Comment: please specify some more information to enable us to follow through. If what you want is to modify the script so as to restart your server everytime you remove a usb drive it is better to write your own script that wraps `usb remove` and also runs `reboot`.

Comment: where should I call the script ? Is there any existing script which gets call on removing the usb ?

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/71348/why-doesnt-this-udev-rule-trigger-upon-removal-of-the-device ... not about a drive, but the basic principle should still apply.